# Python(Spyder) problems with speed

Tags: python, performance, matlab

when I import (Spyder; scipy loadmat) 3 vectors with 250.000 elements it is impossible to continure working (if i want to write something into Ipython Console - it takes minutes). If i import the same vectors in Matlab, I have no problems.
Is that a Python or a Spyder Problem? Are there any tipps/tricks?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you import the same data from the command window/terminal using ipython directly? I don't have any issues with Spyder 2.3.5.2 with such data. Maybe you need to update your packages?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! no - now i closed "Variable explorer" in Spyder - seems to be a lot faster. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Indeed it might be but unfortunately I don't know anything about it.